# Flipped camera with Google VR

Tags: unity, google-cardboard

I just imported latest Google VR SDK into Unity and made a simple scene that has only Main Camera, plane, and single zombie just standing there with T-Pose.

In Main Camera, I added GvrPointerPhysicsRayer component, and it has GvrReticlePointer as child object.

Running in Unity Editor seems fine but when I build and run, whole world is just flipped.

I can't find any related issues about this anywhere, and struggle with this almost a day.

Why camera flipped and how do I fix it? What am I missing?

Using Unity 2019.1.0f2 and gvr-unity-sdk@1.200. Any advice will very appreciate it.

P.S. I saw the warning message in project settings - default orientation:

> Virtual Reality Support is enabled. Upon entering VR mode, landscape left orientation will be the default orientation unless only landscape right is available.

This message never disappear whatever default orientation selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by downgrading Unity to 2018.3.